# How to specify Ec2 Instance Attributes in a AWS::EMR::Cluster CloudFormation Template?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, amazon-emr

Very new to AWS and looking at EMR and hoping for some direction and information here. I want to create a cloud formation template for EMR using `AWS:EMR:Cluster`, however I don't see a way to specify my EC2 Attributes like, `Security Groups` and `EC2 Instance profile`.

I am looking at the resources here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-emr-cluster.html

Can you direct me how this accomplish this from a cloudforatemplate?

I saw the `AdditionalInfo` do I add the Ec2 JSON template there ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should configure the [Instances](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-emr-cluster.html#cfn-emr-cluster-instances) property. Each instance is a [JobFlowInstancesConfig](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-emr-cluster-jobflowinstancesconfig.html).

For instance profiles, provide a [JobFlowRole](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-emr-cluster.html#cfn-emr-cluster-jobflowrole). All EC2 instances in the EMR cluster assume this role.

Comment: When I add an `EbsConfiguration` could this EBS volume be encrypted? I thought an option would be in the `VolumeSpecification` .

Comment: EBS-encrypted volumes are not supported, per http://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ManagementGuide/emr-storage-ebs.html.

Comment: Hmm.. Is there any way I can add the JSON for the "AWS CloudFormation AutoScaling EBS Block Device Property Type"  in the `EbsBlockDeviceConfigs` instead of using `VolumeSpecification` ? That has the encrypted option. Still figuring out the limits with this...

Comment: It's not a limitation of the CloudFormation template, as far as I know. It's a limitation of the EMR service itself.